# How to add optgroup in dropdown where values are loaded from SQL

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, optgroup

I am trying to add an optgroup in a dropdown where the values are loaded from SQL DB. The code below works great as it is, however all my tries to add an optgroup at the top for specific values are ending no where:

```
<select name="make[]" id="make[]" onchange="getModels_add_more
                                             (this.value,'2','modelContainerAddMore
                                             <?php echo $i;?>');">

            <option value="">Any</option>

               <?php while(!$rs_makes->EOF){?>

            <option value="<?php echo $rs_makes->fields['id'];?>">
                  <?php echo $rs_makes->fields['title'];?>
            </option>

               <?php $rs_makes->MoveNext(); } ?>
</select>
```

I am also arranging the makes by alphabetical order and placing make="Other" at the end with this code. Maybe i cannot succeed in my efforts because of those how two codes work together.

```
    $qry_makes  = "SELECT * FROM ".$tblprefix."makes Where type ='2' and status ='1' 
                  ORDER BY CASE WHEN title= 'Other' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, title ASC";

    $rs_makes   = $db->Execute($qry_makes);
```

I am trying to achieve something like this in the dropdown:

```
Any
Audi
BMW
Lexus
Mercedes
---------
Acura
Alfa Romeo
Alpina
Aston Martin
Bentley
Cadillac
```

Also, i am not pasting my failing code as it might be entirely wrong. I am looking for the cleanest way to do this.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do post your failing code, as that's much much more relevant than working code.  Also, post the html output you are trying to get along with the html output currently have.

Comment: So you want to put the first (five) options before the --- into one optgroup, and the rest into another?

Comment: Basically, yes. "Any" should be only the defualt value. Then the next four in a optgroup and then the "-----". I am not sure if the rest of the values should be in a second optgroup or just as they are listed now...this is why i need some help.

Comment: @BradG - Is your question about the correct way to use an `<optgroup>` element?  Or, are you asking how to generate `<optgroup>` elements with PHP?

Comment: Both. I am not sure that what i ahve tried so far is correct so i am asking what is the correct way and how to generate it with PHP.